# How to install buffer scroll on Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, windows-7-x64

I'm having trouble installing [bufferScroll](https://github.com/titoBouzout/BufferScroll) package on to Sublime Text 3. I have been reading on the net and as I realized you have to install manually; to download package from git and place folder to your \Packages folder in Sublime. I did that but it's not picking up. I'm on win 7 64bit and Sublime is ver. 3126.

Thanks xD

Comment: Have you tried raising your question in the specific forum https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/bufferscroll/2949 ? Tito is a brilliant operator who responds to feedback fast and that seems to be a more likely way to get in contact than via SO.